# Why does the Combobox.FindName() method always return null?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, combobox, wpf-controls

I have defined Combobox's ItemSource in List object. I want to reach the ComboBoxItem by using FindName() method but it always returns null. I have tried ApplyTemplate() at the beginning and I also have tried to reach the Item using Combobox.Template. Here is my code. Any suggestions?

```
List<string> subjectsList = e.Result;
cbCategory.ItemsSource = subjectsList;
cbCategory.SelectedItem = cbCategory.FindName("DefaultChatSubject");
```

By the way, I do not have any problem about the Items in ItemSource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`FrameworkTemplate.FindName` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *Finds an element that has the provided identifier name*. From the linked page on MSDN:

> If the element has child elements, these child elements are all searched recursively for the requested named element.
>
> FindName operates within the current element's namescope. For details, see [WPF XAML Namescopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx).

In order to use the `FindName` method successfully, the child element that you are looking for *must* have their `Name` property set. As it is somewhat unlikely that a data bound collection of items will have the `ComboBoxItem.Name` property set, it is also unlikely that this will work for you.

A better way to set the selected item is like this:

```
cbCategory.SelectedItem = subjectsList.First(i => i.Property == "DefaultChatSubject");
```

Or if your collection items are just `string`s, like this:

```
cbCategory.SelectedItem = "DefaultChatSubject";
```

Answer (score 1):

`FindName` is meant to find a named child element of a FrameworkElement. It does not find an item string in the Items collection of an ItemsControl (like your ComboBox).

You could simply call this instead:

```
cbCategory.SelectedItem = "DefaultChatSubject";
```