# Set selected item in WPF ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

(I've read similar posts but they all had a twist to them that made the solution different)

I'm porting a WinForms app that used this:

```
myComboBox.SetSelected(myComboBox.FindString("Some Text"), true);
```

to select an item programmatically. When porting over to WPF, I tried this but it has no effect (the item does not get selected):

```
myComboBox.SelectedItem = myComboBox.FindName("Some Text");
```

What is the correct way to select an existing item in a ComboBox, in WPF?

Comment: Whats your itemsource?

Comment: You can find the answer here https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476979/why-does-the-combobox-findname-method-always-return-null&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwiEoZyk1v3IAhUD5KYKHew9DuQ&usg=AFQjCNGMrZHFUpcCyZhk-L8amDlp_mxSIg&sig2=KwxsuSAuv6UKhLJYOOlhVw

Comment: The answer depends on your code, [which you haven't provided](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Even the Winforms example you show is frankly not a great approach. In WPF, you should have a collection bound to the `ComboBox.ItemsSource`, and you can set `SelectedItem` to the reference of an element of that collection. How you look it up will depend on the exact implementation of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use SelectedValue. In WPF ComboBox, there are multiple ways to achieve the same thing. So, one syntax to select an item programmatically won't work. There are various ways of adding items to ComboBox.

1. You can set ItemsSource both declaratively or in code.
2. You can add ComboBoxItems etc. See Items property in property window to see various item-types available.

If you are using ItemsSource with string values, then you need syntax like : `cmb1.SelectedValue = "Name1"`

If you are directly adding items like `<ComboBox ...> <ComboBoxItem Content="Name1"/> </ComboBox/>` , then you need

```
foreach (ComboBoxItem item in cmb2.Items)
      if (item.Content.ToString() == "Name1")
      {
         cmb2.SelectedValue = item;
         break;
      }
```

I have posted a full working sample demonstrating how to select an item programmatically in various scenarios. Sample code (can be used as is) :

Pay attention to last one, where you have to use SelectedValuePath.

**Window1.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationBlend.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="Window1" Height="411" Width="749">

<Grid>
    <Grid Margin="30,27,491,276">
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmb1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210" Height="25" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource StyleFocusDefault}">
            <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <sys:String>Name1</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>Name2</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>Name3</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>Name4</sys:String>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbInput1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button1_Click"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Margin="405,27,111,276">
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmb2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210" Height="25" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource StyleFocusDefault}">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Name1"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Name2"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Name3"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbInput2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button2_Click"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Margin="30,207,491,96">
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmb3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210" Height="25" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource StyleFocusDefault}">
            <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <sys:String>Name1</sys:String>
                    <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                    <sys:Int32>123</sys:Int32>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbInput3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button3_Click"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Margin="405,207,116,96">
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmb4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210" Height="25" SelectedValuePath="Name" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbInput4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button4_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
  </Window>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Collections;

namespace WpfApplicationBlend
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee(){Name="Name1", Age=100},
                new Employee(){Name="Name2", Age=101},
            };

            cmb4.ItemsSource = employees;
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cmb1.SelectedValue = tbInput1.Text;
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ComboBoxItem item in cmb2.Items)
                if (item.Content.ToString() == tbInput2.Text)
                {
                    cmb2.SelectedValue = item;
                    break;
                }
        }

        private void Button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (object item in cmb3.Items)
                if (item.ToString() == tbInput3.Text)
                {
                    cmb3.SelectedValue = item;
                    break;
                }
        }

        private void Button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cmb4.SelectedValue = tbInput4.Text;
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
comboboxName.SelectedIndex = yourIndex;
```

e.g.

```
combobox1.SelectedIndex = 2;
```